# Who uses RISC and who uses CISC today?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, android, computer-science

Which OS still uses RISC (Reduced Instruction Set Computing)  and which uses CISC(Complex Instruction Set Computing) Architecture?
Can any one tell me which OS uses which instruction set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the OS that uses RISC or CISC, it's the processor.

x86 and x64 are CISC so any OS that runs on them is using a CISC instruction set.

ARM, MIPS, Atmel AVR, PIC, most everything else that is intended for low-power and mobile devices, and IBM's POWER machines are RISC CPUs.

Many OSs, including Windows and various *nix flavors, have been ported to both RISC and CISC processors.

Comment: Windows (Windows 10 IOT) and (Windows RT) and (Windows Phone 7,8, and 10) run on RISC hardware also.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said Windows has been ported to both RISC and CISC. In the past there have been other RISC ports of Windows  NT: MIPS R4000, Alpha, and Power PC.

Comment: I missed that part.  lets be honest nobody remembers Windows NT running on those platforms anymore except the few people that might have actually used it on those platforms.

Comment: It's a proud and lonely thing to be an Alpha fan. :D

Comment: Though, modern X86es are Riscy though their instruction set it CISC. much much much too broad

Comment: Their microarchitecture is RISC. This is used to implement the CISC instruction set that we see.